# Getting list of orders belonging to a customer in square

Tags: square

I have a question about the Square API
I need to get a list of items purchased by by customers.
I see there is an order endpoint, but I need order IDs to get order information.
My transactions dont seem to have any order numbers.
where can I find the order ids belonging to my customers?

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this, you'll need to utilize multiple endpoints.

First, V2 `ListTransactions` will return an array of transactions, and if a customer is associated with a transaction, there will be a `customer_id` field. However, if you did not attach an order to the transaction, then there will not be an `order_id` present.

Just to clarify: in order to have an `order_id` you must do `CreateOrder` prior to calling `Charge`. This will create an order, which you can attach to a transaction to have itemizations (`order_id` is an optional parameter in the `Charge` endpoint). See the first reference link for more details.

If you do not have an `order_id`, you will need to then use V1 `RetrievePayment` (note that the `id` parameter for `RetrievePayment` is the `tender_id` not the `transaction_id` from V2 transaction). This endpoint will provide you with itemizations when you don't have an order.

References:
https://docs.connect.squareup.com/cookbook/orders-and-transactions
https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1#get-payments

Comment: Thank you! I was able to get all the data I needed this way.